# How to copy a file from local to s3 using spark as a single file with the given name?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am looking for ways to move a file from local filesystem to s3 with spark apis with the given fileName. The below is creating file with Part000. How to avoid this?

```
  val df = spark.read.textFile("readPath")
      df.coalesce(1).write.mode("Overwrite")
        .save("path"))
```

Comment: Why not use the s3 client from the Java SDK or the file API instead of Spark?

Answer (score 0):

This worked

```
      val dstPath = new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(inputFilePath)
      val conf = spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration
      val fs = org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(conf)
      fs.setVerifyChecksum(false)

      org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(
        new File(localfilePath),
        dstPath.getFileSystem(conf),
        dstPath, true,
        conf
      )
```